# Unable to push elements in two dimensional list in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I pushed subset list in subsets, two dimensional list but the returned value  is an empty two dimensional list, Why ?

```
public class Solution {
  public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {

    List<Integer> subset = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();

    int x = (int) Math.pow(2,nums.length);
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<nums.length;j++){
            if((i & (1<<j))!=0)
                subset.add(nums[j]);
        }
        Collections.sort(subset);
        subsets.add(subset);
        subset.clear();
    }
    return subsets;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at your code,

```
 subsets.add(subset);
 subset.clear();
```

you are adding your list, and then wiping it content.

I suggest you to move instantiation of `subset` to your loop, then on each iteration you will have new subset element

Answer (score -1):

When you call `List#add(var)` you're storing the same reference that `var` points and now that reference is pointed from two places: inside `List` and from `var`. Since you don't store a copy of the list but the same list referenced by `var` and `List` is mutable, when you change the state of `var`, this change will be also reflected in the list stored inside the other container.

In your current code, you're calling `subset#clear` after adding `subset` into `subsets`, so since you're clearing the contents of `subset`, the list object reference stored in `subset` will also be affected (because it's the same list after all). If you want to keep adding elements using the same list, you should create a new object reference, like this:

```
subsets.add(subset);
//subset.clear();
subset = new Arrayist<>();
```